# Honda Terminal Pin

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, connector

[image]

Looking for insight into the type of terminal pin that this is. It is from a 2008 Honda Accord. It measures approximately 5.8 mm wide. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you asking what type it is or where it goes? It is the female side of a typical spade connector.  What it connects to I wouldn't have a clue. Also wouldn't know why it has a waterproof seal over the wiring.

Comment: It actually is a pin meaning it snap locks into a connector. So basically im just asking what style it is.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is a [spade connector](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=automotive+spade+connector&crid=KEBKODZYJYF9&sprefix=automotive+spade+connector%2Caps%2C69&ref=nb_sb_noss_2). This is a very typical automotive connector.